# Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI won't boot after upgrade from 13.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, uefi

Upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 has resulted in a system that is not bootable.

The system consists of two disks: One with Windows 8 (/dev/sdaX) and one with Ubuntu 14.04 (/dev/sdbX). I was previously booting using an EFI partition /dev/sda2, but the Ubuntu upgrade installer has rendered this inoperative: it fails to a gparted fallback screen. /dev/sdb was originally a legacy MBR/BIOS-based system. I have attempted to create an EFI partition on /dev/sdb1, but I am not sure if I did it right. Boot-repair fails to fix either EFI partition.

Both Windows and Ubuntu are bootable with the assistance of super grub disk, but that is only the way I can get either system to boot.

Secure boot is not enabled.

Boot information is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7622020/

Do you have any recommendations for me? This looks like the bug given in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977 , but there is no clear resolution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) (It looks like you may have tried it at some point in the past but I see no evidence that it's currently installed.) Use the CD-R or USB flash drive version from the [rEFInd downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) for testing. If that doesn't work, you'll have done no more harm and you can move on to some other approach; but if it does work to boot both Linux and Windows, you can install the Debian package (either single-shot using the package from the downloads page or by using the PPA referenced at the bottom of the downloads page).

Comment: Would you recommend installing it on my sda or sdb?

Comment: It shouldn't matter; use whichever one is currently mounted as `/boot/efi`.

Answer (score 0):

The [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) bootloader did the trick. My system's EFI firmware does not remember the symbolic "refind" name, however: it only remembers devices, and it will always try and boot the device default. To get around this, I had to install refind from the `install.sh` script with

```
./install.sh --usedefault /dev/sdXX
```

Read the [install guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#extra_installsh) before using this option. If you use the wrong /dev entry, you could wipe out all your data.

It might be useful if the PPA version of refind had some dpkg-reconfigure style option to that extent.